# Limit scp from only a particular group of systems for a group of users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp, blocking

Allow scp from only a particular group of systems for a particular group. I think an example will be more effective to understand my requirement.

Users : user1, user2, user3 utpto user20 ( All this user have separate credentials for access TargetPC )

ClientPCs : PC1,PC2,PC3,PC4  upto PC20 ( all have common credentials to login)

TargetPC : TGTPC ( OS:Ubuntu )

IP Address of all the systems are static ( users don't have rights to modify this )

My requirement is  user1 to  user10 should  able to do scp to  TGTPC using their credentials from PC1 to PC10 ONLY ( if they try to do scp from any other system it should fail)

same way user11 to  user20 should  able to do scp to  TGTPC using their credentials from PC11 to PC20 ONLY ( if they try to do scp from any other system it should fail)

Comment: Should these restrictions just apply to scp? Or to ssh connections in general? In other words, should these users be allowed to make ssh connections without scp from PC1 and PC11? How about from hosts besides those two?

Comment: @Kenster These restrictions only for scp. Users are allowed to do ssh to anywhere.

Comment: Then restricting their ability to run scp will be pretty pointless. For someone familiar with unix command-line tools, there are plenty of ways to transfer files through an ssh connection without using scp.

Comment: @Kenster I already removed binaries & from the default path which may be use for file transferring ( and using restricted bash to allow for selected users ). if required we can block ssh too , in our design there is no necessity for login to other systems.